# Undeclared identifier CTFramesetter

Tags: ios, ios4, undeclared-identifier

I'm building an iPhone application and trying to create a savePDFFile method by using the Core Text Framesetter.

However, I'm getting the undeclared identifier CTFramesetterRef error for the following line -

```
    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(currentText);
```

I tried to investigate this error and although my project includes the CoreGraphics framework it seems that I still need to add the ApplicationServices framework.
The problem is that I couldn't locate  the ApplicationServices framework/library on my Mac (I tried to "add other" framework as well but couldn't find it).

Is there a way to add it or download it if it's not installed on my computer?

Many thanks,

Dudi Shani-Gabay

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#import <CoreText/CoreText.h>
```

I don't see it written in any official docs.  Just ran across it through trial and error.  Apple still haven't updated the iOS dev docs with Core Text documentation that is targeted toward iOS developers.